# iOS 7 - Is there really a way to do reliable polling via background fetch without Push Messages?

Tags: ios7

I have an application where I need to create local notifications via polling without doing push - primarily due to client infrastructure limitations and their security model.

I've read: http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html, I've seen David Chan's WWDC presentation - where single push messages kick off download tasks - but what I truly need is background fetch - on a regular basis - like every ten minutes - in iOS 7.

I've seen the VOIP hacks. No. What non-hack way is there to do this without user interaction or push messages? Any examples you can point me to?

Here's what I know:

1. Background data tasks will work in the debugger but if you can get a console on an IPA, you'll quickly find out they really are prohibited (thereby invalidated many examples).
2. Background URL tasks require custom delegates - but fetch completion handlers are iffy. This too I found with an IPA and console.
3. I would love to avoid using the AFNetworking lib - for something quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

Background fetch is not a reliable solution - you are at the mercy of the OS, and it is not very merciful. Abusing iOS background modes is not a reliable solution - Apple is known to reject applications that enable background modes, such as location, VOIP and music playback, without a legitimate reason. Background URL tasks are not something you can rely upon to wake your app; they will wake it, but the app will not be awake enough in the background to enqueue a background URL task.

Your best and most intended method is still background fetch, but be prepared to be disappointed. Your app will not be woken app in the interval you need. Also, the user can kill the app in the app switcher screen, causing your app to never wake up until opened.

No real reliable method other than push. You need to insist with your client for the sake of user experience.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no "reliable" way to do that on iOS. With the background fetch API you are not guaranteed to have process run when you would like it run. As you've said, you've already looked at the API so i'm probably telling you something that you already know. A local notification wouldn't solve your issue either as this isn't a way that you can wake your application up and kick off network events. This is behavior that Apple doesn't want as this would negate the whole purpose of their background task coalescing.

You really need to have a push mechanism in place for something like this, so if this is something that is needed, then you may have to stress that to the client.